# How can I allow IP addresses of my LAN and block IP addresses of WAN like Tmeter software?

Tags: networking, server, wine

How can I do this without software like Tmeter? Is there any software like Tmeter for Linux?

I was going to use Tmeter by using Wine but an error occurred:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDaEc.png)

[If I play OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIptd.png)

Help me 
please,
I'm using Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, TMeter is some kind of firewall application. I don't think it will work with Linux, even under WINE - Linux is a fundamentally different operating system to Windows and WINE can't fix that.

Instead, I suggest you look at the various firewall applications available in Ubuntu - [such as GUFW](https://gufw.org/).

I think GUFW comes installed by default, but if not you can install it manually. It calls itself "Firewall Configuration" in the Applications lens in Ubuntu.

If it's not installed and you're comfortable using the terminal, you can install GUFW with

```
sudo apt-get install gufw
```

Or you can search the Software Centre for it.

The Ubuntu Documentation is pretty good at giving an introduction to GUFW, [check it out](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw).